# scikitlearn - how to model a single features composed of multiple independant values

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

My dataset is composed of millions of row and a couple (10's) of features.

One feature is a label composed of 1000 differents values (imagine each row is a user and this feature is the user's firstname :

```
Firstname,Feature1,Feature2,....
Quentin,1,2
Marc,0,2
Gaby,1,0
Quentin,1,0
```

What would be the best representation for this feature (to perform clustering) :

1. I could convert the data as integer using a `LabelEncoder`, but it doesn't make sense here since there is no logical "order" between two differents label

   ```
   Firstname,F1,F2,....
   0,1,2
   1,0,2
   2,1,0
   0,1,0
   ```
2. I could split the feature in 1000 features (one for each label) with 1 when the label match and 0 otherwise. However this would result in a very big matrix (too big if I can't use sparse matrix in my classifier)

   ```
   Quentin,Marc,Gaby,F1,F2,....
   1,0,0,1,2
   0,1,0,0,2
   0,0,1,1,0
   1,0,0,1,0
   ```
3. I could represent the `LabelEncoder` value as a binary in N columns, this would reduce the dimension of the final matrix compared to the previous idea, but i'm not sure of the result :

   ```
   LabelEncoder(Quentin) = 0 = 0,0
   LabelEncoder(Marc)    = 1 = 0,1
   LabelEncoder(Gaby)    = 2 = 1,0

   A,B,F1,F2,....
   0,0,1,2
   0,1,0,2
   1,0,1,0
   0,0,1,0
   ```
4. ... Any other idea ?

What do you think about solution 3 ?

---

**Edit for some extra explanations**

I should have mentioned in my first post, but In the real dataset, the feature is the more like the final leaf of a classification tree (`Aa1`, `Aa2` etc. in the example - it's not a binary tree).

```
             A                         B                    C 
      Aa          Ab             Ba          Bb         Ca      Cb
    Aa1  Aa2  Ab1 Ab2 Ab3     Ba1 Ba2     Bb1 Bb2    Ca1 Ca2 Cb1 Cb2
```

So there is a similarity between 2 terms under the same level (`Aa1` `Aa2` and `Aa3`are quite similar, and `Aa1` is as much different from `Ba1` than `Cb2`).

The final goal is to find similar entities from a smaller dataset : We train a `OneClassSVM` on the smaller dataset and then get a distance of each term of the entiere dataset

Comment: To perform clustering, i.e KMeans, you first need to define a distance function for your features. KMeans by default works in the euclidean space (euclidean distances), but I guess this makes no sense since you only have categorical data. I mean, for 3 sample data `a, b, c`, with `F1a = 5, F1b = 8 and F1c=9`, does makes sense for you the distance between `F1a` and `F1c` to be larger than `F1a` and `F1b`? (since the numerical difference is bigger). Or for you only matters `F1x != F1y` regardless its values?

Comment: An addition to my above comment: Try doing a clustering in the [Hamming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) space.

Comment: Building off of imaluengo's comment, how do you intend to cluster these data? This will help inform what to do with your column that you want to transform.

Comment: Thanks imaluengo for the thoughts. There is notion of distance between the tags. I just edited my anser with extra informations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is largely one of one-hot encoding. How do we represent multiple categorical values in a way that we can use clustering algorithms and **not** screw up the distance calculation that your algorithm needs to do (you could be using some sort of probabilistic finite mixture model, but I digress)? Like user3914041's answer, there really is no definite answer, but I'll go through each solution you presented and give my impression:

**Solution 1**

If you're converting the categorical column to an numerical one like you mentioned, then you face that pretty big issue you mentioned: you basically lose meaning of that column. What does it really even mean if Quentin in 0, Marc 1, and Gaby 2? At that point, why even include that column in the clustering? Like user3914041's answer, this is the easiest way to change your categorical values into numerical ones, but they just aren't *useful*, and could perhaps be detrimental to the results of the clustering.

**Solution 2**

In my opinion, depending upon how you implement all of this and your goals with the clustering, this would be your best bet. Since I'm assuming you plan to use sklearn and something like k-Means, you should be able to use sparse matrices fine. However, like imaluengo suggests, you should consider using a different distance metric. What you can consider doing is scaling all of your numeric features to the same range as the categorical features, and then use something like cosine distance. Or a mix of distance metrics, like I mention below. But all in all this will likely be the most *useful* representation of your categorical data for your clustering algorithm.

**Solution 3**

I agree with user3914041 in that this is not useful, and introduces some of the same problems as mentioned with #1 -- you lose meaning when two (probably) *totally* different names share a column value.

**Solution 4**

An additional solution is to follow the advice of the answer [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22/k-means-clustering-for-mixed-numeric-and-categorical-data). You can consider rolling your own version of a k-means-like algorithm that takes a mix of distance metrics (hamming distance for the one-hot encoded categorical data, and euclidean for the rest). There seems to be some work in developing k-means like algorithms for mixed categorical and numerical data, like [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169023X0700050X).

I guess it's also important to consider whether or not you *need* to cluster on this categorical data. What are you hoping to see?

Comment: Thanks for your detailled answer and the link to k-modes classifier. I was thinking of solution 3 as an intermediate between 1 and 2 (not as detailled as 2 but with a really lower dimension) . I've edited my first post with more precision about what the data is really and what I intend to do. Could you explain a bit more which distance you would calculate using a cosine ? I'm not sure to understand what you mean here.

Comment: Sure. The idea of cosine distance you see is most commonly not actually a distance metric. Intuitively, it is *kind of* like the angular distance between two vectors, comparing the orientation of two vectors more so than the magnitude. You can find more info in the scipy docs [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html). There are ways to convert the cosine distance to angular distance, which is a proper distance metric. The wikipedia page [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) might be useful to learn more about this.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 3:**
I'd say it has the same kind of drawback as using a `1..N` encoding (solution 1), in a less obvious fashion. You'll have names that both give a 1 in some column, for no other reason than the order of the encoding...
So I'd recommend against this.

**Solution 1**:
The `1..N` solution is the "easy way" to solve the format issue, as you noted it's probably not the best.

**Solution 2**:
This looks like it's the best way to do it but it is a bit cumbersome and from my experience the classifier does not always performs very well with a high number of categories.

**Solution 4+**:
I think the encoding depends on what you want: if you think that names that are similar (like John and Johnny) should be close, you could use characters-grams to represent them. I doubt this is the case in your application though.

Another approach is to encode the name with its frequency in the (training) dataset. In this way what you're saying is: "Mainstream people should be close, whether they're Sophia or Jackson does not matter".

Hope the suggestions help, there's no definite answer to this so I'm looking forward to see what other people do.

Comment: I think that OP intends to cluster the data rather than classify anything.

Comment: @NBartley You're right, I got confused as he does mention a 'classifier' in his explanations. I think what I wrote still holds except maybe for the comment about solution 2. I'm not sure why but I don't feel super comfortable with solution 2 for clustering either if you have numerical features thrown together with it in the algorithm.

Comment: I generally agree. I think it largely depends upon what the OP wants to measure the distance of when it comes to the names. Is it similarity in names, or just the presence/absence of names?

Comment: The idea of frequency is interesting. There is a kind of similarity between names : in the real dataset, the feature is more like the final leaf of a classification tree, let me edit my first post with the detail